# Search for empty string & null value

Tags: mongodb, go

I am having an issue I can't seem to figure out.
In our database I we have some values "events.locationId" is the KEY in mongo. I need to write a check to find BOTH `"events.locationId": ""` & `"events.locationId": null`, In my go code I can search for the empty string no problem, OR search for the nil value, but how does one do both?

```
type timecard struct {
    ID           string     `json:"_id" bson:"_id"`
    UID          string     `json:"uid" bson:"uid"`
    CompanyID    string     `json:"companyId" bson:"companyId"`
    Events       []event    `json:"events" bson:"events"`
    ScheduleInfo []schedule `json:"scheduleInfo" bson:"scheduleInfo"`
}

type event struct {
    LocationID string `json:"locationId" bson:"locationId"`
    ShiftID    string `json:"shiftId" bson:"shiftId"`
}

type schedule struct {
    ID         string `json:"_id" bson:"_id"`
    LocationID string `json:"locationId" bson:"locationId"`
}

    tcs := lookupTimecards(c.String("companyid"), c.Bool("global"), dB.Database)

    var insertModels []mongo.WriteModel
    for _, t := range tcs {
        for ei, e := range t.Events {
            for _, s := range t.ScheduleInfo {
                if e.ShiftID == s.ID && e.LocationID == "" {
                    lid := fmt.Sprintf("events.%d.locationId", ei)
                    insertModels = append(insertModels, mongo.NewUpdateOneModel().SetFilter(
                        bson.D{{Key: "_id", Value: t.ID}},
                    ).SetUpdate(
                        bson.D{{Key: "$set", Value: bson.D{
                            {Key: lid, Value: s.LocationID},
                        }}},
                    ))
                }
            }
        }
    }

    if len(insertModels) > 0 {
        shared.BulkWrite("timeCards", insertModels, dB.Database)
    } else {
        log.Println("No updates needed")
    }
```

The bulk write portion is it actually going out and writing to the db, it takes a collection, inserModels & mongo.Database as input.

If I run this portion here the tcs goes into mongo and grabs the documents and adds them to the timecard struct, if I check for e.LocationId == "" it will go out and update those fields for me but it does not do the null values, likewise if I change it to a *string (event.LocationId) struct, it updates the null values but not the empty string.

Below is a sample document with the potential 3 different values for events.locationId

```
{ 
    "_id" : "Q9Xobbp3G3prTrkBp", 
    "uid" : "wXWa49mSJ9AHHZyJM", 
    "companyId" : "WbcpnstGwYRcCP86x", 
    "start" : ISODate("2021-03-22T03:59:00.000+0000"), 
    "end" : ISODate("2021-04-04T03:59:00.000+0000"), 
    "approved" : true, 
    "events" : [
        // THIS IS A VALID OBJECT AND NEEDS TO BE SKIPPED
        {
            "attendanceId" : "nWCkkgXb9RqyWXnuz", 
            "start" : ISODate("2021-03-28T04:00:00.000+0000"), 
            "end" : ISODate("2021-03-28T04:00:00.000+0000"), 
            "locationId" : "nWCkkgXb9RqyWXnuz", 
            "locationCode" : "", 
            "eventDate" : ISODate("2021-03-28T04:00:00.000+0000"), 
            "eventType" : "AC_DEDUCTION", 
            "detail" : "Sick Pay", 
            "duration" : "0", 
            "appendValue" : null, 
            "payType" : {
                "_id" : "rkzXu6sjeEhsMSjfN", 
                "name" : "Sick Pay", 
                "description" : "Sickpay", 
                "payCode" : "EnFnxqLXqZugFzdGH", 
                "rateAdjustment" : NumberInt(1), 
                "companyId" : "WbcpnstGwYRcCP86x", 
                "usePrefix" : false, 
                "excludeFromBanking" : true, 
                "ignoreFromWorkedHours" : false, 
                "ignorePremiums" : false, 
                "category" : "Deduction", 
                "rateselector" : "Flat Rate", 
                "taxCalculation" : "None", 
                "multiplier" : NumberInt(1)
            }, 
            "payCode" : {
                "_id" : "EnFnxqLXqZugFzdGH", 
                "name" : "Sickpay", 
                "description" : "Sick Pay Awake", 
                "companyId" : "WbcpnstGwYRcCP86x"
            }, 
            "payTypeName" : "Sick Pay", 
            "rate" : null, 
            "week" : NumberInt(2)
        }, 
        // THE locationID null needs to be found
        {
            "attendanceId" : "oZNS4zZT5Wgea8vNZ", 
            "start" : ISODate("2021-03-28T20:00:00.000+0000"), 
            "end" : ISODate("2021-03-29T04:00:00.000+0000"), 
            "locationId" : null, 
            "locationCode" : "", 
            "eventDate" : ISODate("2021-03-28T20:00:00.000+0000"), 
            "eventType" : "AC_DEDUCTION", 
            "detail" : "Sick Pay", 
            "duration" : NumberInt(8), 
            "appendValue" : null, 
            "payType" : {
                "_id" : "rkzXu6sjeEhsMSjfN", 
                "name" : "Sick Pay", 
                "description" : "Sickpay", 
                "payCode" : "EnFnxqLXqZugFzdGH", 
                "rateAdjustment" : NumberInt(1), 
                "companyId" : "WbcpnstGwYRcCP86x", 
                "usePrefix" : false, 
                "excludeFromBanking" : true, 
                "ignoreFromWorkedHours" : false, 
                "ignorePremiums" : false, 
                "category" : "Deduction", 
                "rateselector" : "Flat Rate", 
                "taxCalculation" : "None", 
                "multiplier" : NumberInt(1)
            }, 
            "payCode" : {
                "_id" : "EnFnxqLXqZugFzdGH", 
                "name" : "Sickpay", 
                "description" : "Sick Pay Awake", 
                "companyId" : "WbcpnstGwYRcCP86x"
            }, 
            "payTypeName" : "Sick Pay", 
            "rate" : null, 
            "shiftId" : "QiWNodCRCCnGXTrRc", 
            "week" : NumberInt(2)
        }, 
        // The locationId needs to be found
        {
            "attendanceId" : "oZNS4zZT5Wgea8vNZ", 
            "start" : ISODate("2021-03-29T04:00:00.000+0000"), 
            "end" : ISODate("2021-03-29T04:00:00.000+0000"), 
            "locationId" : "", 
            "locationCode" : "", 
            "eventDate" : ISODate("2021-03-29T04:00:00.000+0000"), 
            "eventType" : "AC_DEDUCTION", 
            "detail" : "Sick Pay", 
            "duration" : "0", 
            "appendValue" : null, 
            "payType" : {
                "_id" : "rkzXu6sjeEhsMSjfN", 
                "name" : "Sick Pay", 
                "description" : "Sickpay", 
                "payCode" : "EnFnxqLXqZugFzdGH", 
                "rateAdjustment" : NumberInt(1), 
                "companyId" : "WbcpnstGwYRcCP86x", 
                "usePrefix" : false, 
                "excludeFromBanking" : true, 
                "ignoreFromWorkedHours" : false, 
                "ignorePremiums" : false, 
                "category" : "Deduction", 
                "rateselector" : "Flat Rate", 
                "taxCalculation" : "None", 
                "multiplier" : NumberInt(1)
            }, 
            "payCode" : {
                "_id" : "EnFnxqLXqZugFzdGH", 
                "name" : "Sickpay", 
                "description" : "Sick Pay Awake", 
                "companyId" : "WbcpnstGwYRcCP86x"
            }, 
            "payTypeName" : "Sick Pay", 
            "rate" : null, 
            "week" : NumberInt(2)
        }
    ], 
    "employeeName" : "Adam Power", 
    "approvedByEmployee" : "wXWa49mSJ9AHHZyJM", 
    "approvedEmployeeOn" : ISODate("2021-04-02T20:47:21.023+0000"), 
    "approvedAdminOn" : ISODate("2021-04-06T15:20:58.950+0000"), 
    "approvedByAdmin" : "fScsctnCM86csG7R6", 
    "managerApproved" : true, 
    "locked" : true
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you just want to use go's logical or operator [||](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/go/go_logical_operators.htm), like so:

```
 if e.ShiftID == s.ID && ( e.LocationID == nil || e.LocationID == '')
```

EDIT

Unless I'm missing something I don't really see where you "query" your documents, however you just want to use either [$in](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/query/in/) or [$or](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/query/or/) to query multiple conditions, like so:

```
cursor, err := coll.Find(
    context.Background(),
    bson.D{{"LocationID", bson.D{{"$in", bson.A{"", nill}}}}})
```

Comment: Sorry I should have been more clear about my question, the problem is not go running either of those that I have above, the problem is it does not update one or the other. Like if I look for the emptry string "", the $match query does not find the null values, and likewise I search for the null value and it doesn't $match the empty string "". the problem is not golang but $matching BOTH data types that can potentially be in the database.

Comment: _" ...$matching BOTH data types that can potentially be in the database."_ I think the _or_ operator is the correct way. For a given document, a field can be defined only once. Hence, you can have either of the two values: `null` _or_ `""`. (another possibility is the field may not exist; but, the check for `nil` covers this condition too).

Comment: I'm not sure I understand the question and the code snippets you shared, i did edit in how to "query" a single field for multiple conditions, however from your code snippets that did not look relevant? if this is not what you're looking for then I think you should edit your question to be more clear

Comment: I have edited my question above with a more complete chunk of code for you.

Comment: And to clarify the issue is not how to do it with mongo I know how to do it there, the question is how to do a check with golang, the timeCard collection is an array of objects, (events is the array), each object has a locationId field, that can be a valid string "kjashdkaslhdkashkj", "" OR null, the valid string I need to skip but the "" OR null values need to be corrected.